# Displaying relationship data inside Django templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I followed the process of creating multi user type from this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_driver = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Owner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

I have a driver and owner profile with field user which has a OneToOneField relationship with the user model

```
class OwnerProfile(models.Model):

    ]
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='owner_profile')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


class DriverProfile(models.Model):

    ]
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='owner_profile')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Owners can create Cars

```
class Car(models.Model):

    car_owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='car_owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_make = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    …
```

While drivers can create CarRents

```
class CarRent(models.Model):


    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='rented_car', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='driver_renting', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    …
```

I have a detailView

```
class ActiveRent(DetailView):
    model = CarRent
    template_name = 'app/ActiveRent_detail.html'
```

in my template i tried to access data in the Owner profile using each of the following `{{object.car_owner.owner_profile.phone}`, `{{object.car.ownerProfile.phone}}`, `{{object.ownerProfile.phone}}` but nothing is working.

**Thanks** *for your help in advance*

Comment: Your detail view is for the `CarRent` model not for `Car`, so `{{ object.car.car_owner.owner_profile.phone }}` would give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to provide the actual data you want to work with in the `context` of the view:**

---

You can achieve this by adding the following line in the `view` of your template.

1. When it's a class:

```py
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfileDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) # get the default context data
        context['object'] = Owner.objects.all() # This is just an example of how you would get all the owners of a car.
        return context
```

Here, you simply override the method that gets the `context` and add some values.

---

2. In the `render()` method in a function `view` (In your case it does not seem to be the case):

```py
def your_view(request):
    return render(request, 'app/template.html', context={'object': Owner.objects.all()}
```